# Explain why Chrome interprets Arial emojis differently than in any other font - it adds a gender symbol

Tags: google-chrome, emoji, font-family

Could someone explain why some emoji have the gender symbol added to them when using Chrome and an Arial font?
[Arial facepalm renders with gender symbol in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNmpv.png)

chrome version: 63.0.3239.132

Here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style> 
.emoji {
  font-family: Times;
}
</style>
<body>

<p style="font-family: Arial">Arial Facepalm with symbol ‍♂️</p>
<p style="font-family: Arial">Arial Facepalm without symbol ‍️</p>
<p class=emoji>Times Facepalm with symbol ‍♂️‍</p>
<p class=emoji>Times Facepalm without symbol ‍</p>
<p>No font Facepalm with symbol ‍♂️</p>
<p>No font Facepalm without symbol ‍</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you selected the emoji from an Apple device interface, because the gender symbol is inherent in the string that gets pasted. It's actually four Unicode characters:

- A generic facepalm character: [U+1F926](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F926) `&#x1F926;`
- A zero width joiner: [U+200D](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/200D)`&#x200D;` (the glue)
- A male gender symbol: [U+2642](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/2642)`&#x2642;` (the default)
- A variation selector: [U+FE0F](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/FE0F)`&#xFE0F;` (seems redundant)

Replace the gender with a female sign and you've got a "woman face palm"

```
&#x1F926;&zwj;&#x2640;
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQQvPW

But as you've spotted - [not with Arial](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVVxNj) in Chrome - and apparently only Arial and only Chrome from what I've tested.

Although I can answer why the symbol is there, I can't tell you why Chrome can't render the Unicode composite rules in just this font. I can only guess that it's a bug in Chrome and will be fixed at some point.

If you need to render a male face palm in Arial you still can. Just use the generic base character on its own: `&#x1F926;`. If you need a female emoji then you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks for adding some context around the way emoji are created using multiple unicode characters. My question regarding chrome/arial still stands, however. I agree that it's probably some sort of bug. It'd be nice to understand why Chrome isn't rendering the composite rules.