# Emoji Issue: Emoji "Man Raising Hand: Medium-Light Skin Tone" appears as 2 emoji's instead of 1

Tags: emoji

The emoji "Man Raising Hand: Medium-Light Skin Tone" (as seen on https://emojipedia.org/man-raising-hand-type-3/) appears in my web page as 2 emoji's, namely the female version on this one + the male symbol after it, like this: ♂

The HTML uses UTF-8, so emoji's should work.
I'm typing this in a text field, not saving or doing anything else.

When searching on Google, the Google search results also appear as a the female version of this emoji + the male symbol after it.

What could be going on here?

Does it have something to do with Chrome (latest version) on Mac? Or is there something else? To me, it looks like Google is having the same issue, as their search results also display it wrong.

Copy pasting the emoji here also doesn't work for me. When I paste, the same woman raising hand + male symbol appears as well, instead of the man raising his hand.

I can however, paste this male version in Sublime Text editor. Then pressing backspace turns the emoji into the female version and pressing backspace again, changes the woman's skin tone.

So, how do I make this man raising his hand emoji work on a web page?

Comment: The second emoji is (I am not so sure) called [Emoji modifiers](https://emojipedia.org/modifiers/). Also there may be somewhere [Zero-Width-Joiner](https://emojipedia.org/zero-width-joiner/) take place.

Comment: That's interesting, but doesn't really give me a clue on how to support it on a web page. Do we need UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 perhaps?

Comment: @Wouter I made a little search, but sorry for can't find anything related to "Emoji ZWJ sequence support for devices / software". However there are some "suggested" combinations. I believe this are some support made by platforms (system and software), but nothing related to UTF-16 or UTF-8.

Comment: Then I found [Issue 566258, Chrome on Mac doesn't render ZWJ emojis correctly](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=566258).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain why Chrome interprets Arial emojis differently than in any other font - it adds a gender symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757153/explain-why-chrome-interprets-arial-emojis-differently-than-in-any-other-font)

Answer (score 0):

Emojis can have [modifiers](https://emojipedia.org/modifiers/) and [Zero-Width-Joiner Sequences](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequences/). The [emoji mentioned in the original question](https://emojipedia.org/man-raising-hand-type-3/), as the link to Emojipedia said, is actually a combination of 3 emojis: 
 [Person Raising Hand](https://emojipedia.org/happy-person-raising-one-hand/),  [Medium-Light Skin Tone](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-modifier-fitzpatrick-type-3/) (modifies the skin color), 
[♂️ Male Sign](https://emojipedia.org/male-sign/) (modifies the gender/sex).

As you can see, the modifier for skin tone already works, but the sequence for gender doesn't.

As per [Issue 556771, Support Emoji Joiner Sequences](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=556771) said, this issue is already fixed, but in the bottom there is someone still hitting this issue, and remains a possible alternate like `data:text/html,<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>%F0%9F%99%8B%F0%9F%8F%BC%E2%80%8D%E2%99%82%EF%B8%8F</body></html>`.

```
%F0%9F%99%8B%F0%9F%8F%BC%E2%80%8D%E2%99%82%EF%B8%8F
%F0%9F%99%8B                                        U+1F64B 
            %F0%9F%8F%BC                            U+1F3FC 
                        %E2%80%8D                   U+200D  Zero Width Joiner
                                 %E2%99%82          U+2642  ♂
                                          %EF%B8%8F U+FE0F  Variation Selector 16
```

Besides, I tried manually insert ZWJ between ♂ and VS16 after this all, and the emoji changed to the expected ‍♂️ in my Firefox on Linux. I don't have a Mac, so I am not sure if these alternates works in Chrome for Mac.